# Using Python to access DLL functions with Pointers

Tags: python, c++, dll

I'm trying to build a Python app to access data inside a proprietary file format (*.abf, by Axon Instruments). The fine folks who specify the format have released a DLL that contains functions you can use to open these files, read/write, etc.

So far so good. I've read a number of posts on SO and around the web about using `ctypes` to import DLLs, and this seems to work fine - but many of the useful functions in the DLL I'm trying to interact with take integer pointers as an argument, and `ctypes` doesn't have a data type for interacting with that.

Am I out of luck?  Do I need to write this app in a different language, or is there some way to hack this together in Python?

Thanks all,
-Steve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look deeper. Ctypes does have [Pointers](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html#passing-pointers-or-passing-parameters-by-reference).

```
from ctypes import *
f = c_float()
f_pointer = pointer(f) # full pointer functionality
f_byref = byref(f) # minimalistic pointer just for passing by reference
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, @Berserker! Mmm, yes, I should have been more specific. Ctypes has pointers, but only char and void - [link](http://imgur.com/3pe7t6A)

Comment: It points out the pointer() and byref() functions in the link I gave you. But oh well, I updated my answer to help you more.